# Adding a function to type Duration under momentjs in TS

Tags: typescript, momentjs, prototype

Can't add a function to Duration interface under momentjs package

I'm trying to get the months by a round of 30 days (version 2.24.0 return 0.94~ month for 30 days and I need it to be one)

for some reason i cant do this:

```
        Duration.getRealMonths = function () {
          return Math.floor(this.as('days')/30);
        }
```

Here's a stack blitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-example-6kknck

I expect this:

let duration: Duration = moment.duration(30,'days');

to return 1 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have imported the type `Duration`. Use `moment.duration` instead which should be of type `Duration`.

Another problem is that your function `getRealMonths` does not exists on Duration, so you can't simply add it.

Comment: moment.duration is a function that returns a Duration. i want to extend that type

Comment: I know. In your example, you try to do it in the constructor - any reason for  this?